# Ajax call (using jquery) gets no more responses after 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, tomcat

In fact, I have a JavaScript application (jQuery) that is sending a request to a Java function which is supposed to send back data (success case) to my ajax function.
In the success case, I go on with my application; in error case, I stop my procedures and display the error message to the user.

But when the Java code takes more than 5 minutes to send a response to my Ajax call, this one (ajax code) doesn't (work / respond / go on /) get any response anymore ...

I tried setting up a timeout limit to `600000 ms` (so 10 minutes) but I still get the same problem (and ain't got any error messages or output, which could have been helping me).

So if anyone's got an idea on the source of this problem, I'd be grateful.

Here is some piece of code if it may make it clearer :

### JSP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*  performing some layout changes  */

    //
    preValidationDisplay();
}      

function preValidationDisplay() {
    /*  performing some layout changes  */

    setTimeout("getValidationResult()", 500);    
}


function checkReadLogFile() {
    $.ajax({
            url: logFileUrl,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result)
            {                   
                $("#progressBarToResize").width( 
                    '' + parseFloat(result.trim()) + '%' );
            }
        });
}


function getValidationResult() 
{
    var timer = setInterval("checkReadLogFile()", 1000); 


    $.ajax({
        url: '<s:url value="doValidation"/>',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        //timeout : 600000,
        success: function(result, status)
        {
            // Do something
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, errorStr){
            // Do something
        }
    });
}
```

### java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doValidation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processValidationResults(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestHeader("Connection") String conn) {
    ValidationResult validationResult = null;
    JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    JSONObject progressMap = (JSONObject) session.getAttribute("progressMap");
    String uploadedFilePath = progressMap.getString("filePath");
    String realMimeType = progressMap.getString("realMimeType");
    long fileSize = progressMap.getLong("fileSize");
    String ctxPath = request.getContextPath();

    // INVOKE the VALIDATION ENGINE
    try {
        validationResult = validationEngineService.getValidationResult(uploadedFilePath, ctxPath);
        resultJson = JSONObject.fromObject(validationResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        validationResult = null;
        resultJson.put("errorMsg", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        response.getWriter().print(resultJson);
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: any code? server side function ?

Comment: Your server side lasts for more than a minute? You should probably optimize that because, as @Christian responded, no request should be longer than 30ish seconds...

Comment: Are you setting an onerror handler to get errors with the Ajax calls? Have you watched the calls with a proxy like Fiddler or Charles?

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with HTTP, never expect a connection to take longer than half a minute.

Either use WebSockets or Comet (long polling).

See, there are many parties that might decide to stop your connection:

- web browser, firewall/router/isp, web server (eg: Apache), server scripting language (eg: PHP)

The only time I disable this on the PHP side is when I want PHP to keep running even after the user stopped the connection (which, by the way, I have enable yet another setting).

Comment: I'd gladly help, but I didn't make up the rules myself. I don't know anything of your code, but if this is a regular ajax call, there's no other way than to replace it with something else.

Comment: The thing is that I'm working on a web-portal that's already up and there'd probably be many things to adapt...

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, i'm not sure if i could help much but have you tried checking which event is triggering the ajax call? I made a silly mistake once by sending an ajax request on keydown, i later found out that instead of keydown , i needed to use keyup since thats the event triggered once the value of the textbox is set to the text + key recently entered.
So you could try a keyup or change the event in jQuery. If this is on localhost, its not a good sign....first determine whats causing the problem, the frontend or backend.

Things to do:
1) Change event type in jQuery

```
$("#elem").live("keyup",function() {//send req});
```

2) Check apache log. If your on ubuntu or something similar, you can go to /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: As far as I see it, he is intentionally sending requests that last this long.